# Prompt toLowerCase not executing correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm unsure why this isn't executing properly? It's so simple however I can't warp my head around it:

```
response = prompt(question.toLowerCase());
```

When I insert something into the prompt and I console.log it it seems to come back with uppercase letter that I added when I inserted the value into the prompt.

I want toLowerCase to convert any value into lowercase when submitted.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you are setting lower caption of prompt, not the entered text.
You have to use:

```
response = prompt(question).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: NOTE: If the user cancels, this creates an error. So, while it does work, it would be error free if it were applied to the response after the prompt is made.

Answer (score 0):

As you want `toLowerCase()` to convert any user response to lowercase, try

```
resp = prompt('Blah blah', '')
lcrp = response.toLowerCase();
```

As `prompt` or `window.prompt` accepts two arguments, one for the message to be displayed in the prompt and another as a default if the user did not provide any response.

`prompt` returns the user input as a string. So, `resp.toLowerCase()` should convert `resp` to lowercase.